# A student is provided with 500 mL of 600 ppm solutions of fructose. What volume of this solution in millilitres contains 0.15 fructose?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

> A student is provided with 500 mL of 600 ppm solutions of fructose.  What volume of this solution in millilitres contains 0.15 fructose?

Does this mean that I just have to use 600 ppm as the concentration and the 0.15 as the weight? Like this:

\begin{align*}
{600 \space ppm}
&=\frac {0.15 g}{x}\cdot 10^{6} \\
x&=\frac {0.15 }{600}\cdot 10^{6}  \\ 
x&=250 \space mL\\
&
\end{align*}

And when can 500 mL be used?

Comment: 0.15 whats of fructose? grammes, mols?

Comment: I think if you don't provide the units of 0.15 this question will be close because is unclear what you are asking...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's $0.15gm$ of fructose,$$ppm=\frac{Weight\;of\;solute_{(in\;gm)}}{Weight\;of\;solution_{(in\;gm)}}10^6$$
Since density of water is $1gm/ml$, $500ml$ of water would weigh $500gm$
$$\therefore600=\frac{W_b}{500}10^6$$
$$\therefore W_b=0.3gm$$

Thus, $500ml$ of water contains $0.3gm$ of fructose. You can find out what volume will contain $0.15gm$ of it.